# Current Transformer Analysis giving error

Tags: current-transformer

So i have tested about 10 CTs in a transformer using Omicron CT-Analyzer and except for one CT, every result came fine.

[image]

As i am still in my learning phase, i am not sure why these two parameters failed when everything else is fine (Excitation curve, Current Ratio, VA Burden etc, every thing is fine).

Please help me understand as to why these failed. You can refer to the pdf of the full CT test report, can be downloaded from this link (https://tssd.egnyte.com/dl/GUBWoVLOD3).

Thank you and looking forward to hearing for the possible solutions.

Comment: Send it back to the supplier and get them to analyse it.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the failed CT to the passing CT?

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy class will not be guaranteed for burdens above rated burden or below 25% of the rated burden (IEC spec of 0.2 is tight).

Insufficient  Ampere-turns will affect error at lower current test levels but also affect saturation levels above rated current.  Permeability and temperature of Nickel steel will also affect inductance from Ampere-turns.   This is my understanding no 1st hand experience of this class of CT’s.

Confirm the CT rating and test levels that failed with actual results for margin of error by discussion with OMICRON and OEM.  Then see if another parameter not specified above can isolate the root cause. By all means correlate your test results with factory for “standard” methods by analog correlation of results, rather than pass fail.  Then you may compute /compare accuracy of tester at CT OEM vs your tester and confirm with OMICRON and OEM for a solution.  Replace part , measure/test tester for correlation with calibration  and assess risk of failure and benefit of your new experience in least time+cost.